# PostreSQL93 + postgis2 using MacPorts

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, macports

I'm trying to update my postgres installation from 9.2 to 9.3 on my mac using macports. I removed all my postgres-related installations, then I installed postgres93, but when I install postgis (`sudo port install postgis2`), macports automatically downloads and installs postgres92 (so the 93 version is left without postgis extension)… why? How can I specify to have postgis2 for postres93?

Comment: Maybe the port for postgis hasn't been updated to 9.3, and still depends on 9.2? Check the manifest of the port. These days all the Cool Apple Kids seem to be using homebrew instead; it comes with a different set of pain points, but may be worth looking at. (Personally I just `yum install postgresql-9.3` but I'm on an OS with package management).

Comment: currently brew has yet to provide postgres93… macports is better imo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved!!!

I re-installed postgres93 by specifying it as the variant to use with postgis2:

```
sudo port install postgis2 +postgresql93
```

Comment: Thank you, this saved me :D And yes, I stick with macports vs. homebrew.